# gain access in RecyclerView to all elments in same row

Tags: java, android, xml, android-recyclerview

[image: RecyclerView]

i have a recyclerview as shown in the picture every row contains
a two button

i have added onClickListener to Button-A

is there anyway to access Button-B in the same row if the user click on Button-A
in the same row ?

```
class BooksHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public BooksHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        Download=(Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.download);
        pb=(ProgressBar)itemView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1) ;
        Download.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Download.setVisibility(Button.INVISIBLE);
                new DelayTask().execute();

            }
        });
    }
}

public class DelayTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {
    int count=0 ;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pb.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        while (count < 5) {
            SystemClock.sleep(1000);
            count++;
            publishProgress(count * 20);
        }
        return "Complete";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        pb.setProgress(values[0]);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        SystemClock.sleep(100);
        pb.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);
        Download.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);
        Download.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

Download is Button has declared in Adapter
pb is ProgressBar has declared in the Adapter

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: i have added the code

Comment: what is your requirement ? do you want to access both button on single click?? if so check my comment else if you want to have separate click on each button check my answer below

Comment: i asked about button as example 

but i alredy have a progressbar in the row 

i want to access the progressbar in the same row

Answer (score 1):

you can implement onClickListener in your viewHolder

Example

```
static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
Button button1;
Button button2;

public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    button1 = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button2 = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.button2);

    button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    button2.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view == button1) {
        // your action here
    } else if (view == button2) {
        // your action here
    }
}
}
```

Comment: no my question is if the user click on the button1

is there anyway to gain access on the button2 in the same row

Comment: yes you can execute performClick() action on button2 while button1 is clicked . `Download.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Download.setVisibility(Button.INVISIBLE);
                new DelayTask().execute();  button2.performClick();//This will initiate click action on button2 when Download button is clicked

            }
        });`

Comment: i want to gain only the progressbar in the same row
but it access the progressbar in the last row

Comment: Be clear with your question, in the comment you asked to gain access on button2 in the same row, without understanding your issue or code that you have implemented you cannot expect to provide correct solution, so pls post both your xml and code

Answer (score 0):

i think you are asking how to access button B when button A is get clicked?

Do as shown in code snippet below in your adapter class which populating RecyclerView

```
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
        public Button buttonA, buttonB;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            buttonA = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnA);
            buttonA.setOnClickListener(this);
            buttonB = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnB);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(v.getId()==R.id.btnA){
                buttonB.setText("Button A is clicked");
            }
        }
    }
```

Run your app, initially it shows screen like..

[image]

Then click button A of any row you will see caption of button B changed in same row. Like in image below..
[image]